# Winium Automation- How to press Enter or Escape on keyboard using Winium with java?

Tags: testing, automation, winium

I tried all of these but it's still not working

```
  driver.findElementByName("3").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  driver.findElementByName("Form1").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
  driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Though, clicking works. Here's the command that I use.
     driver.findElement(By.name("3")).click();

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I already make if worked by using this command.

```
 driver.findElement(By.name("3")).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as follows

```
driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys("{ESCAPE}");
driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys("{ENTER}");
```